# PHP Query causes SQL Server Tables to disappear and reappear

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

We have a website that accesses a SQL Server 2005 server for one query.  Currently, the site is in ASP, we are moving it to PHP, and the PHP one is currently being tested.  After we run a few successful queries on the PHP site, it returns the "Error in database query.  Please try again later" line in the code below.  When I rewrote that line with sqlsrv_errors to elaborate, it told me that the table didn't exist.  There are about 40 tables in the database, but after the error happens it only shows 8 of them in Management Studio.  However, if I allow it to sit for about 5 minutes, all of the tables are restored.  No matter how many times the old ASP site is used, the table does not do this.  However, when the tables disappear from using the new site, the old site shows inaccessible for a few minutes until the tables re-appear in SQL Server management studio. I didn't see any kind of connection limits on the SQL Server, so I don't know whether it's something I'm doing in the PHP SQL queries or within the SQL Server properties.

```
<?php
include ("dbvals.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST['lastnamebox'])) {
    $dbhandle = sqlsrv_connect($dbServer, $connectioninfo);
    if($dbhandle == false){
        echo "Error connecting to database. Please try again later. ";
    }
    else{
              $query = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE LastName LIKE '%' + ? +
                  '%' AND InactiveFlag = 'N' ORDER BY LastName, FirstName";

          $params =  array();
          array_push ($params, $_POST['lastnamebox']);

          $results = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, $query, $params);
          if($results == false){
            echo "Error in database query. Please try again later.";
            //This is printed when database tables temporarily disappear
        }
        else
        {
            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($row){
                do{
                    echo "<tr><td class='tablecell'>";
                    echo $row['LastName'] . "," . $row['FirstName'] . "<br>";
                    echo "Address: " . $row['Address'] . "<br>";
                    echo "City, State, Zip: " . $row['CSZ'] . "<br>";
                    echo "</tr></td'>";
                }while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC));
            }
            else{
                echo "No results found. Please try another query.";
            }

        }
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($results);
    sqlsrv_close($dbhandle);
}
else {
    echo "Please type a value in the search box.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Does monitoring the connections from PHP in SQL Profiler show anything interesting?

Comment: Never spit out a fixed/unchanging DB error message. Especially when you KNOW there's problems. `if (!$result) { var_dump(sqlsrv_errors()); die(); }` would TELL you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, it tells me the table is an invalid object name (which is because it's "missing"), but of course doesn't tell me why that happened.  That's what I had in lieu of the standard message. This is only a test site as it is.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(5) "42S02" ["SQLSTATE"]=> string(5) "42S02" [1]=> int(208) ["code"]=> int(208) [2]=> string(89) "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Person'." ["message"]=> string(89) "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Person'." }

Answer (score 1):

The $query is wrong to begin with. Change it to:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE LastName LIKE '%' + ? +
              '%' AND InactiveFlag = 'N' ORDER BY LastName, FirstName";
```

Not sure about the tables disappearing though. What driver are you using?

Comment: Sorry, query was slightly altered so true names weren't displayed and I somehow put two extra ands in there.  The real query does work, but after a few queries it loses access.  I'm using PHP 5.4 Threadsafe.

Comment: I see. As suggested by Marc B I'd use `sqlsrv_configure` directive to log everything.

Answer (score 1):

Just another issue I'm seeing with the code not sure if it's related to your problem. or another copy error but here it is.

```
        if ($r1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)) {
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

The first fetch should also have '($results,, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)'

Additional that check is going to eat the first returned record which may or may NOT be what you intended.

Also it is possibly that PHP seeing some results in the while as false even though they aren't and the server is still waiting on you to finish getting the rest. Seen code like that cause 'Server has got away' errors in MySQL which could be what is going on here as well.

Not sure of the syntax but a sqlsrv_clode_cursor() just before the connection close might also fix your issue if there's some kind of connection polling going on. Could be simply running out of connection or getting old one in a incorrect state.

Comment: Thanks...I'm fairly new to PHP so syntax errors and general buffoonery aren't going to be out of the question here. I removed the check as it was removing the first record. However, I could only find info on CloseCursor for PDO queries.  Would that apply to a non PDO query?

Comment: Cursor is a feature of SQL and I'm sure SQLServer has them but how you manage them in this driver I can't tell you. Might read through the commands on http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php and the comments for more info. sqlsrv_free_stmt() should be corect but I only have used mysqli or PDO. I'm base most of my answer from my understand of the SQL standard commands themselves because that's what the server sees. Your main job will be getting the driver you are using to sent the right things or working around it when doesn't. I believe PDO will also work with SQLSrv so might look at it

Comment: sqlsrv_free_stmt() seems to be working, it has at least lasted longer after the addition of this.  Just going to have to see if I can replicate what was happening.  If not, may try PDO instead, sqlsrv does have the option.

Comment: Finally failed under that, tried PDO with CloseCursor and still get the drop eventually.  I've never seen tables just vanish and reappear like this. Perhaps I'll try this on Serverfault also to see if anyone has any SQL Server suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Person WHERE AND LastName LIKE

Looks like there something missing between the WHERE and AND to me.

I don't know SQL Server really so it could allow that but it's not standard SQL. Depending on how it's reacting to that error I could see it 'Going away' so to say and reporting tables missing.

Comment: See comment on giessebi's answer...had typos in translation.